# nvidia-docker - can cuda_runtime be available while building a container?

Tags: darknet, nvidia-docker

While attempting to compile darknet in the build command of a docker container I constantly run into the exception `include/darknet.h:11:30: fatal error: cuda_runtime.h: No such file or directory`.

I am building the container from the instructions here: https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/Deploy-on-Amazon-EC2.  I have a simple `Dockerfile` I am testing with - the relevant parts:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:9.2-runtime-ubuntu16.04
...
WORKDIR /
RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN git clone https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet.git
WORKDIR /darknet
# Set OpenCV makefile flag
RUN sed -i '/OPENCV=0/c\OPENCV=1' Makefile
RUN sed -i '/GPU=0/c\GPU=1' Makefile
#RUN ln -s /usr/local/cuda-9.2 /usr/local/cuda
# HERE I have been playing with commands to show me the state of the docker image to try to troubleshoot the problem
RUN find / -name "cuda_runtime.h"
RUN ls /usr/local/cuda/lib64/
RUN less /usr/local/cuda/README
RUN make
```

Most of the documentation I see references using the nvidia libraries when running a container, but the darknet compiles differently when built with `gpu` support so I need `cuda_runtime.h` available at build time.

Perhaps I misunderstand what `nvidia-docker` is doing - I'm assuming that `nvidia-docker` exists because the Nvidia code must be installed on the actual host machine and not inside the container & they use some mechanism to share the "native" code with the containers so the GPU can be managed - is that correct?

Should I even be trying to build `darknet` when building my container or should I be installing it on the host machine, then making it available somehow to the container?  This seems to go against the portability of the containers but I can live with some constraints to get access to the GPU.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> FROM nvidia/cuda:9.2-runtime-ubuntu16.04

Your image only has bits and pieces of CUDA-9.2 needed to *run* a CUDA app, but does not have the bits needed to *build* one.

You need to use -devel variant.